# How to find out value of a particular attribute index in core data model iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I have a core data table called `Word`, which has 5 `attribute`. They are `word`, `synonym`, `definition`, `sentence` & `date`. I am showing all data in `UITableView`. But the value `index` of my tableView is not same as code data object `index`. Let me show my code:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Words"];

    self.wordListArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.wordListArray = [[moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    self.wordInWordListArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.wordListArray count]; i++)
    {
        self.words = [self.wordListArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [self.wordInWordListArray addObject:self.words.word];
    }

    if ([self.wordListArray count] != 0)
    {
        self.wordDic = [self sortedDictionary:self.wordInWordListArray];
    }
```

I show data in my `tableView` based on the new `self.wordDic` dictionary. Where all data in arranged by alphabetically. Now I want to delete data from my `tableView`. For that I do the following.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *secTitle = [self.keyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSMutableArray *secData = [self.wordDic objectForKey:secTitle];
    NSString *str = [secData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Words" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"word like %@", [secData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *matchingData = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

        for (NSManagedObject *obj in matchingData)
        {
            [context deleteObject:obj];
        }
        [context save:&error];

        // remove info from tableView array
        [self.wordListArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.homeTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[secData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

But it is got crashed. The reason is for this line:

```
[self.wordListArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

`wordListArray` hold my core data original objects and I want to delete a value in my table view whose index is different from this index.

My question is, as you can see I have the attribute value here `[secData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]`, using this how can I get it's index value in `self.wordListArray` object list which has the original core data index?

actual `Word` table in core data:

```
word     synonym     definition     sentence     date
-----------------------------------------------------
Exact    xxx         xxx            xxx          xxx
Aim      xxx         xxx            xxx          xxx
Brave    xxx         xxx            xxx          xxx
Work     xxx         xxx            xxx          xxx
Arise    xxx         xxx            xxx          xxx
Wise     xxx         xxx            xxx          xxx
Bubble   xxx         xxx            xxx          xxx
Zoom     xxx         xxx            xxx          xxx
```

In my `tableView` I sort them like this:

```
word     synonym     definition     sentence     date
-----------------------------------------------------
Aim      xxx         xxx            xxx          xxx
Arise    xxx         xxx            xxx          xxx
Brave    xxx         xxx            xxx          xxx
Bubble   xxx         xxx            xxx          xxx
Exact    xxx         xxx            xxx          xxx
Wise     xxx         xxx            xxx          xxx
Work     xxx         xxx            xxx          xxx
Zoom     xxx         xxx            xxx          xxx
```

Now I want to delete, say `Bubble` row from my tableView, which current index in `UITableView` is `3`, but in my actual core data object it's index is `6`. How can I get the original index of my value `Bubble` in core data object?

If you understand my problem please reply. Thanks a lot in advance.
Have a good day.

**Edited**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([selectedIndex isEqual:indexPath])
    {
        // Expanded Cell
        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = kHomeTableViewCellID;
        HomeTableViewCell *cell = (HomeTableViewCell *)[self.homeTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if (!cell)
        {
            cell = [[HomeTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        NSString *secTitle = [self.keyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSMutableArray *secData = [self.wordDic objectForKey:secTitle];
        [secData sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
        NSString *data = [secData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.wordLabel setText:data];

//        NSManagedObject *words = [self.wordListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//        [cell.wordLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [words valueForKey:@"word"]]];

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, but in that function, you have already solved how to turn an indexPath into an index into wordListArray.

You also need to call "deleteRows" inside an animation block.

So, replace this code:

```
    // remove info from tableView array
    [self.wordListArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.homeTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[secData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

With:

```
    // remove info from tableView array
    NSInteger wordArrayIndex = [self wordArrayIndexForTablePath:indexPath];
    [self.wordListArray removeObjectAtIndex:wordArrayIndex];

    // batch deletions must be in an animation block
    [self.homeTableView beginUpdates];
    [self.homeTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.homeTableView endUpdates];
```

Here is wordArrayIndexForTablePath (you need to fill stuff in)

```
   - (NSInteger)wordArrayIndexForTablePath:(NSIndexPath)indexPath {

      NSString *tableData = /* refactor out the section/row part from cellForIndexPath and look this up with indexPath */;

      for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.wordListArray.count; ++i) {
          // I have no idea how all of your arrays and structures map 
          // to each other.  You need to find the object in the array
          // that matches your section/row table data
          if (/* you need to figure this part out -- use tableData, I guess */) {
               return i;
          }
      }
      // you probably want to assert here if you think it's always there
      return -1; 
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have edited my post with `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` code. Here I have used the filtered `NSArray`. Not the core data object array.

Comment: I added some pseduo-code. You need to fill it in with your knowledge of your data-structures.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Sir. I do it, and it's working perfectly. :)

Answer (score 2):

Any particular reason you are not leveraging [`NSFetchedResultsController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/)? That is one of its use cases.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Well, not like that. It could be an option for sure.